# pdfnet - re-opening a pdf after returning to a page with NavigationCacheMode.Enabled

Tags: pdf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, pdftron, pdfnet

I have 2 pages on a windows store app project.

First page displays a pdf file in a small part of the page, and i have a button that when i press i open the other page with the pdf loaded in full screen.

On page1 i have this on its constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

Im using PDFtron to view and edit the pdf files.
on Page1 `OnNavigatedTo` method i have this

```
                    pdftron.PDFNet.Initialize();
                    MyPDFViewCtrl = new pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl();
                    PDFViewBorder.Child = MyPDFViewCtrl;
                    MyToolManager = new pdftron.PDF.Tools.ToolManager(MyPDFViewCtrl);
                    pdfViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

and this on xaml

```
<Grid  x:Name="pdfViewer" Background="Blue"   Canvas.ZIndex="111" Visibility="Visible" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="PDFViewBorder" Background="Green" Grid.Row="0"/>

                    </Grid>
```

to open the pdf i have something like this:

```
folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.DataDirectory, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
       file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(document.fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
       docpdf = new PDFDoc(file);
       MyPDFViewCtrl.SetDoc(docpdf);
       Debug.WriteLine(MyPDFViewCtrl.GetPageCount());
```

So the problem is this:
When i enter page1, it displays the pdf correctly, i then press the button and navigate to page2 where it shows the file in fullscreen correctly, when i go back to previous page the file seems to be loaded correctly to the docpdf variable (it shows the correct number of pages on the Debug.WriteLine) , but it doesn't show on the MyPDFViewCtrl, i get a empty Green Square.

Do i need to enable any sort of parameter?